# Is there a way I can edit the middle of a file in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, struct, fstream

I am working on a project in C++ that requires I use a struct called `CustomerAccounts` to get information like name, address, city, etc. I used a `do..while` loop to allow the user to enter a new record, display a record, change an account's information, or delete an account.

My problem with this comes with dealing with the file. I want to know if there is a way where I can edit the middle of a file if the user chooses to change an account's information, or if they decide to delete an account.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int choice, customer=0;
    fstream file;
    CustomerAccounts account[10];
    file.open("output.txt");
    file<<"";
    file.close();
    
    do{
        cout<<"1. Enter new records into file.\n";
        cout<<"2. Display an account's information.\n";
        cout<<"3. Delete an account.\n";
        cout<<"4. Change an account's information.\n";
        cout<<"5. Display contents of all accounts.\n";
        cout<<"6. Quit";
        cout<<"\n\nEnter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    file.open("output.txt", ios_base::app);
                    getInfo(account[customer]);
                    addToFile(account[customer], file, customer+1);
                    customer++;
                    file.close();
                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                    int num;
                    cout<<"Enter the account number you wish to see: ";
                    cin>>num;
                    displayAccount(account[num-1], num);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    int num2;
                    cout<<"Enter the account you want to delete: ";
                    cin>>num2;
                    account[num2-1].address="";
                    account[num2-1].balance="";
                    account[num2-1].city="";
                    account[num2-1].lastPay="";
                    account[num2-1].name="";
                    account[num2-1].phone="";
                    account[num2-1].state="";
                    account[num2-1].zip="";
                    for(int i=num2-1;i<customer+1;i++){
                        account[i-1].address=account[i].address;
                        account[i-1].balance=account[i].balance;
                        account[i-1].city=account[i].city;
                        account[i-1].lastPay=account[i].lastPay;
                        account[i-1].name=account[i].name;
                        account[i-1].phone=account[i].phone;
                        account[i-1].state=account[i].state;
                        account[i-1].zip=account[i].zip;
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    int num3;
                    cout<<"Enter the account you wish to change: ";
                    cin>>num3;
                    cin.ignore( numeric_limits <streamsize> ::max(), '\n');
                    cout << "Enter name: ";
                    getline(cin, account[num3-1].name);
                    cout << "Enter address: ";
                    getline(cin, account[num3-1].address);
                    cout << "Enter city: ";
                    getline(cin, account[num3-1].city);
                    cout << "Enter state: ";
                    getline(cin, account[num3-1].state);
                    cout << "Enter zip: ";
                    getline(cin, account[num3-1].zip);
                    cout << "Enter phone number: ";
                    getline(cin, account[num3-1].phone);
                    cout << "Enter balance: ";
                    getline(cin, account[num3-1].balance);
                    cout << "Enter last pay: ";
                    getline(cin, account[num3-1].lastPay);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    file.open("output.txt");
                    string getContent;
                    cout<<"All Accounts: \n";
                    while(getline(file, getContent))
                        cout<<getContent<<endl;
                    cout<<endl;
                    break;
            }

        }while(choice!=6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless your file contains fixed size records, and your editing consists of replacing them, 1:1, this is not possible, neither in C++ nor in any other language, and you must write out a new file, from scratch, from beginning to end.

Comment: ... and what Sam says is perfect when you start with building your own database. It's also fun when you see it start working. I say go for it.

Comment: You can always treat the file like an array:  first move data down to clear up some space (extending the file length), then write into the space you freed up.  Most applications create new files rather than edit the original file.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's funny how many people use a file when they should have used a database.  And your suggestion is very cruel.

Comment: @MarkRansom That was not at all my intention!? What? I did that when I was 14 and loved it. It was not a way of saying that it can't be done. It was the oppisite! Do it! It CAN be done.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that would require an added/pre-existing index to know where the records starts.

Comment: Yahya: I did _not_ mean to shut your ideas down - quite the opposite and I will gladly help out.

Comment: @Surt:  You would have to append the last record to the end of the file.  Then write the n-2 record to the n-1 slot.  And keep repeating until you got to where you needed to insert a new record.  I'm not saying its efficient, only that inserting into the "middle" is possible.

Comment: A more efficient method is to append new records to the end of the file.  Each record should have a status flag.  Set the flag to "true" if the record is in use, "false" if the record is deleted.  This allows blocks or records to be reused.  To "clean up", write all the records that are in use to a new file.  Sorting the records is a another task (which is better suited to reading the records into memory, sorting the records in memory then writing to a new file).

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ index files".  Data files are best left alone or minimally changed.  Use other files for ordering the data.

Comment: Lastly, if it walks like a database and smells like a database, you probably want to use a real database and libraries to manage it.

Comment: I don't think this project has a requirement that makes a database needed yet.

Comment: @MarkRansom Is there something in my previous behavior - or did I just use the words wrong? If I come along as cruel regularly, I need to leave. If I made a mistake, I think I can do better.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's nothing you said, it's just how I interpreted it - it seemed a little sarcastic to suggest writing your own database.  Done correctly, it seems like a huge task.  Congratulations to you for tackling it at such a young age.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ok, I can see how it could be seen as sarcastic. That's not how I think I "treat /  follow up" on anything and hope to help.

Thank you for your congratulations and congratulations to you too! Good job!

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did not see that any of your replies were cruel or rude. I am glad with any suggestions that I can get.

Comment: @Yahya I'm glad to hear that. I got a similar suggestion myself when I started and  didn't feel it was out of your grap. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`seekp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) the example from the link is very telling.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
 
int main() {
    std::ostringstream os("hello, world");
    os.seekp(7);
    os << 'W';
    os.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
    os << '!';
    os.seekp(0);
    os << 'H';
    std::cout << os.str() << '\n';
}
```

Outputs "Hello, World!"

Now you need to know the size of your records in bytes, I hope that they only contain fixed types and no pointers.

When you want to delete a record in the middle you can mark it with a `tombstone` a value that your record can't possible contain, postal no. -1 or something.

If you wanted to insert a new record in the middle, you have several options

- move all later records one down
- add it to the end and live with it
- make an index to get the correct position in the file.